# Table partitioning, first attempt - throws errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, partitioning

Working on partitioning task and was following this tutorial [Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146.aspx#).

In the section *Roll the old data OUT and the new data IN to the Partitioned Table* where the author adds the new boundary to the table by using `SPLIT RANGE` technique, my code throws an error: *The associated partition function 'Archive_PF' generates more partitions than there are file groups mentioned in the scheme 'Archive_PS'.', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.*

Here is what I do:

Switch out table called BusinessEvent_Purged is created exactly the same way as the active table, less the `IDENTITY` property on primary key. All the constraints and indexes are set, etc. Then I switch out the data like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [BusinessEvent_Archive]
SWITCH PARTITION 1
TO [BusinessEvent_Purged] PARTITION 1
```

Then I remove the old boundary point by doing the merge:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [Archive_PF]()
MERGE RANGE (DATEADD(day, -394, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)))
```

I'm stripping the time at this point as that is not important for now. And then I attempt to add a new boundary by:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [Archive_PF]() 
SPLIT RANGE (DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)))
```

and that's when I get the error.

I understand that there is a mismatch between partition function and partition scheme, but I'm not certain how to correct it. The tutorial does not mention anything on that.

I also get an error when I perform the following:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [Archive_PF]
NEXT USED [PRIMARY]
```

as the author suggest that merging partition removes the association between file groups and partition scheme. The error I get with this step is: *Cannot alter the partition scheme 'Archive_PF', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.* Yet both PF and PS are present, I'm an admin to my box and clearly this is not what the issue is.

Could some one comment on what I'm not doing right? Thanks!